# How to start and stop a sound in android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a button called " micro" , when I click on my sound is played , and when I click on again it must stop

I tried the code below  but when I click on my button for the second time , the music is played again and again without stopping:

```
        Button micro=(Button)findViewById(R.id.micro);          

        micro.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),
                            R.raw.mymusic);
                    mp.start();
                }
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                     MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),
                                R.raw.mymusic);
                        mp.stop();
                }
                return true;
            }


        });
```

Comment: Why are you using OnTouchListener first of all? if you want to press a button, use OnClickListener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating separate `MediaPlayer` objects. You should just create one that you tell to start and stop as necessary.

Right now you're telling one to start, and then later telling a different one to stop.